# parameters passed to function is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I generated a random number called listingid in function createpost and pass it as an input to function showproductmodal as shown below

```
function creatpost(){
var index;

splitinput.forEach((num, index) => {

     var listingid = (Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5)).toUpperCase()

    console.log(index)

    return CatalogueDB.ref( splitinput[index]).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

            var resultcard = `
            <form id="myform${index}">
            <tr class="tr-shadow">
                                                <td>

                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(${key},${index},${listingid});">Submit</button>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </form>
          `
            container.innerHTML += resultcard;
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            container.innerHTML += "";

            var errorcard = `
                <form id="myform${index}">

            <tr class="tr-shadow">

                                            <td    style="width: 90px;">
                                            <div id="ItemID${index}">${splitinput[index]}
                                            </div>
                                            <div>
                                                <br>
                                                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-1 btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#productModal" onclick="showproductmodal(${splitinput[index]},${index},${listingid})">
                                                    Add Photos
                                                    </button>
                                            </div>

                                            </td>






                                                <td>

                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(${splitinput[index]},${index},${listingid})">Submit</button>

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </form>
          `
            container.innerHTML += errorcard;

        })
});
})


   function showproductmodal(id, index, listingid) {


      console.log(id,index)
  }
```

the problem now is whenever the button is clicked which triggers showproductmodal it says lisitingid is undefined

this is the console error output

> > index.html:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: JJLQ23008PJX0 is not defined
> >         at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:1)

this is the sample parameters passed to the showproductmodal retrieved from the console

> > showproductmodal(42,0,JJLQ23008PJX0)

why is the listingid causing error even when it has been passed to the function? How do I correct this so that I can retrieve listingid in showproductmodal?

Comment: why the down vote?

Comment: There could be several reasons you got downvoted, where one is that the `JJLQ23008PJX0` is not a number, it is technically an alphanumeric _string_, and many here believe you should know that, as it is one of the fundamental things how javascript works, another, your question is badly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote the random string:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" onclick="postitem(${key},${index},'${listingid}');">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `listingid` is not a variable with the name `JJLQ23008PJX0` it will throw an error.

Generally one need to make such id/value be treated as a string, and enclose it in quotes, likes this, where I added single quote's `'`

```
onclick="postitem(${splitinput[index]},${index},'${listingid}')"
```

Some value types works though, as *numbers*, the boolean keywords *true/false*, etc.,